# Regarding ubuntu 18.04 initramfs error

Tags: xubuntu

I am new in ubuntu ,I have an issue with my ubuntu 18.04 at  Lenevo Thinkpad e470 ,i have opened my laptop then a black screen open with initramfs error so how can i fix it..

Answer (score 0):

Type exit

```
exit
```

then type

```
 fsck /dev/sda
 fsck /dev/sda1
 fsck /dev/sda2
 fsck /dev/sda3
 fsck /dev/sda4
 fsck /dev/sda5
```

above any command ask for permission then press `Y`

then wait for a while.
after that type

```
reboot
```

again wait and type

```
exit
```

and wait . It will solve automatically.